# How to mark the observations with given information

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, match

Considering the data collected with 5 minutes time interval with a numeric variable `a`,and a discret variable `acc`, which represents if there's any incident happened(`0` for no incident while `1` for incident):

```
a<-c(1:(288*4))
t<-seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:05:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-05 00:00:00"), by = '5 min')
acc<-rep(0,288*4)
df<-data.frame(t,a,acc)
```

Now I have another data set which has the time(accurates to 1 sec) at which  the incidents happened during the collection period:

```
T<-sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:05:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-05 00:00:00"), by = '1 sec'),size = 5)
```

I want to mark the nearest 2 prior observation's `acc` as 1 according to the time in `T`. For example, if the incident happened at `2016-01-02 07:13:23`, the observations' `acc` with `t` of `2016-01-02 07:05:00` and `2016-01-02 07:10:00` are marked as `1`

How could I manage to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ind <- findInterval(T, df$t)
df$acc[c(ind, ind + 1)] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
library(lubridate)
df$acc=apply(sapply(T,function(x) x %within% interval((df$t - minutes(4)-seconds(59)),(df$t + minutes(4)+seconds(59)))),1,sum)
```

`lubridate` allows for the easy manipulation of dates, `minutes(x)` and `seconds(x)` adds x minutes or second to a period object.
`interval()` is used to create a time interval confined by the time in `df$t` ± 4min59s.
`sapply()` is used to check if any of the time in T is within the interval.
`apply()` is used to collapse the results of `sapply()` (it outputs 1 column for each element in T)

If `T` contains a value that is exactly equal to one in `df$t` such as `2016-01-04 12:05:00 CET` this will only put 1 for this one.